# How do I calculate the momentum matrix element using the Fourier transform?

Tags: fft

I am trying to calculate the momentum matrix element between the ground and first excited vibrational states for a harmonic oscillator using the Fourier transform of the eigenfunctions in position space. I am having trouble calculating the momentum matrix element correctly.

Here is my code

```py
hbar = 1
nPoints = 501
xmin = -5
xmax = 5
dx = (xmax - xmin) / nPoints
x = np.array([(i - nPoints // 2) * dx for i in range(nPoints)])
potential = np.array([0.5 * point**2 for point in x])  # harmonic potential

# get eigenstates, eigenvalues with Fourier grid Hamiltonian approach
energies, psis = getEigenstatesFGH(x, potential, mass=1, hbar=hbar)

# should be 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5 or very close to that
for i in range(5):
    print(f"{energies[i]:.2f}")

# identify the necessary wave functions
groundState = psis[:, 0]
firstExcitedState = psis[:, 1]

# fourier transform the wave functions into k-space (momentum space)
dp = (2 * np.pi) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))
p = np.array([(i - nPoints // 2) * dp for i in range(nPoints)])
groundStateK = (1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * hbar)) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(groundState))
firstExcitedStateK = (1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * hbar)) * np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(firstExcitedState))


# calculate matrix elements
xMatrix = np.eye(nPoints) * x
pMatrix = np.eye(nPoints) * p
# <psi0 | x-hat | psi1 >, this works correctly
x01 = np.dot(np.conjugate(groundState), np.dot(xMatrix, firstExcitedState))
# <~psi0 | p-hat | ~psi1 >, this gives wrong answer
p01 = np.dot(np.conjugate(groundStateK), np.dot(pMatrix, firstExcitedStateK))
```

Comment: This question may be more suitable for https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks. posted there.